# Extraction of main town part of a postcode field

Tags: ms-access

I wish to extract the main part of postcode from full postcode. This could be one or two letters depending on town. i.e. L for L13 5AQ (Liverpool postcode) or LS for LS13 5AQ (Leeds postcode). Can I have a simple Access Query formulae to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would be very careful about relying on this for the town/city as whilst it does often point to the "post town", it might not be the town/city that the whole postcode is located in.

For example the NR postcode relates to Norwich however, also covers large towns like Gt Yarmouth and Lowestoft.

They can also non geographic related, as number six on this list mentions - https://medium.com/@allies/6-common-mistakes-when-capturing-and-storing-uk-addresses-ad72e0cf10c8

> 6. Postcodes don’t always relate to a geographical area
>
> There are several memorable postcodes in PAF® like GIR 0AA for
>   Girobank (it’s just a pity they went and changed their name to
>   Santander).
>
> Don’t rely upon the first two characters always helping you to resolve
>   down to an area.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query to get the first two letters and check if the first 2 characters are alphabetical

```
SELECT LEFT(my_field, 2) FROM tbl WHERE my_field LIKE '[a-Z][a-Z]%'
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, will look at that and see if I can use it as a start to get both. I am an old man who works with old access queries rather than sql statements but will try and convert your idea

Comment: Did not do all I wanted in my Access way of doing things but appreciate the help. Was not really bothered about the area covered by first part of postcode just how to extract either the first 1 or 2 positions in a field depending on whether single alpha or double alpha start to postcode